# Modifying the html style of children component in parent component in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am doing an npm timeline Vue component. But I am facing problems.

**parent component A:**

```html
<script>
export default Vue.extend({
 name: "aComponent",
})
</script>

<template>
   <div class="events-content">
     <ol>
       <slot name="eventsContent"></slot>
     </ol>
   </div>
</template>
```

**children component B:**

```html
<aComponent>
      <template v-slot:eventsContent>
        <li class="selected" ref="event-1">
          <p>
            orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum
            praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla
            adipisci? Con
          </p>
        </li>

        <li>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum
            praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla
            adipisci? Con
          </p>
        </li>
      </template>
</aComponent>
```

Now I want to modify the style of *li* of Children component B in the method of parent component A. That is why I tried to use *ref="event-1"* to access in parent component A, but it doesn't work. I don't want to add too much code in children component B, because it is going to be npm package. So how can I modify each *li* style from children component B in parent component A

Answer (score 1):

The parent component can style the slotted children with its own `<style>` block:

```html
<!-- ParentComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <aComponent>
    <template v-slot:eventsContent>
      <li class="selected">
        ⋮
      </li>

      <li>
        ⋮
      </li>
    </template>
  </aComponent>
</template>

<style>
li {
  color: #444;
}
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-style-slotted-children?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: I want to change the style of the parent component in the children component. not in parent component

Comment: I think you're saying you want to change the *style of the slotted children* (not the style of the parent component itself, which wouldn't make sense to do from the child). Then move the `<style>` to the child component: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-style-slotted-children-pojwe4?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FAComponent.vue)

Comment: Thanks for the demo code, It works if I put .selected style in the Acomponent. But how to make it dynamically? which means it will change the style of selected in a method function of Acomponent?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean if I can change the style of slot in Acomponent in [class binding way](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html)